# React Native - Can't find variable AppRegistry

Tags: react-native

I've just started with react native. I've run:

```
$ react-native init AwesomeProject
$ cd AwesomeProject
$ react-native run-android
```

When it runs on the device shows red screen with:

```
React Native - Can't find variable AppRegistry
```

Comment: Did you import AppRegistry `import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native'`?

Comment: Yes, I've just downloaded the example code from the official page

Comment: And how does your file `index.android.js` look?

Comment: Just downloaded from https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html. react-native init AwesomeProject

Comment: Did you run `npm install`?

Comment: Yes, I've run it

Comment: Add the code involved.

Comment: This is the code: https://snack.expo.io/B1H0HFngb. There is working, but not in my phone.

Comment: Removing npm modules and installing them again fixed the issue.